# Computing % return using groupby returns NaN

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
       city    Year  Asset_Type  TotalTransac  NbBiens     psqm_city
0    Agadir  2010.0      Appart          3225     3156   6276.923077
1    Agadir  2010.0  Maison_Dar            37       37   8571.428571
2    Agadir  2010.0       Villa           107      103   6279.469027
3    Agadir  2011.0      Appart          2931     2816   6516.853933
4    Agadir  2011.0  Maison_Dar            33       32   9000.000000
..      ...     ...         ...           ...      ...           ...
171  Tanger  2019.0  Maison_Dar           268      263  12158.385093
172  Tanger  2020.0      Appart          5223     5180   5760.869565
173  Tanger  2020.0  Maison_Dar           193      192  13500.000000
```

I am trying to compute the % return by `Asset_Type` using the following function:

```
Index_byCity["Returns"] = Index_byCity.groupby(['city','Year','Asset_Type'])['psqm_city'].apply(lambda x: (x - x.shift(1))-1 )
```

But i get an unexpected output

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
       ..
171   NaN
172   NaN
173   NaN
174   NaN
175   NaN
Name: Returns, Length: 176, dtype: float64
```

I don't understand why iam getting this output since dtype shows `psqm_city` as a float.

```
city             object
Year            float64
Asset_Type       object
TotalTransac      int64
NbBiens           int64
psqm_city       float64
dtype: object
```

Can someone help please

Comment: You are grouping by city+year+asset type. If there is only one record in the bin (which, looking at the sample data, is likely), the `shift` in lambda will return `NaN`. Also, `NaN` is a legitimate float value

Comment: Thank you. Thats exactly as you said I should have grouped by city+asset type. Thanks again